# Building error of status code 2 in matlab mex

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, mex

I encounter a building error in compiling a .m file into .mexmaci64.
My matlab version is 2011a, platform Mac OS X 10.6, using a Xcode 3.2.

Error statement:

> ??? Build error: Compilation returned error status code 2. See the target build log for further details.

Target build log:

> 3   In file included from mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:13:
>       4   mphmm_getEstimation_data.h:30: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'xb_emlrtRSI'
>       5   mphmm_getEstimation_data.h:31: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'nc_emlrtRSI'
>       6   mphmm_getEstimation_data.h:32: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'oc_emlrtRSI'
>       7   mphmm_getEstimation_data.h:33: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'pc_emlrtRSI'
>       8   mphmm_getEstimation_data.h:34: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'qc_emlrtRSI'
>       9   mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'xb_emlrtRSI'
>      10   mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:23: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'nc_emlrtRSI'
>      11   mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:24: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'oc_emlrtRSI'
>      12   mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:25: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'pc_emlrtRSI'
>      13   mphmm_getEstimation_data.c:26: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'qc_emlrtRSI'
>      14   gmake: *** [mphmm_getEstimation_data.o]

I highly appreciate if someone can tell me how to solve the error. Please let me know if I need to provide code file. Sorry that I am not professional on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It is a linking error, caused by either some linking arguments are missing or some .h files are missing. It turned out that

> mwmathutils.h

and

> emlrt.h

are out of date for my current matlab version. I replaced the two files, and everything started to work.